# Is it possible to get key value pairs from snowflake api instead rowType?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working with an API from snowflake and to deal with the json data, I would need to receive data as key-value paired instead of rowType.
I've been searching for results but haven't found any

e.g. A table user with name and email attributes

| Name | Email |
| --- | --- |
| Kelly | kelly@email.com |
| Fisher | fisher@email.com |

I would request this body:

```
{
  "statement": "SELECT * FROM user",
  "timeout": 60,
  "database": "DEV",
  "schema": "PLACE",
  "warehouse": "WH",
  "role": "DEV_READER",
  "bindings": {
    "1": {
      "type": "FIXED",
      "value": "123"
    }
  }
}
```

The results would come like:

```
{
  "resultSetMetaData": { 
    ...
    "rowType": [
      { "name": "Name",
         ...},
      { "name": "Email",
        ...}
    ],
  },
  "data": [
        [ 
          "Kelly",
          "kelly@email.com"
        ],
        [
          "Fisher",
          "fisher@email.com"
        ]
  ]
}
```

And the results needed would be:

```
{
  "resultSetMetaData": { 
    ...
  "data": [
        [ 
          "Name":"Kelly",
          "Email":"kelly@email.com"
        ],
        [
          "Name":"Fisher",
          "Email":"fisher@email.com"
        ]
  ]
}


Thank you for any inputs
```

Comment: You can write the SQL so that the data comes back as k-v pairs. Please post a sample of the query run through the API and sample data.

Comment: What API are you using to talk with Snowflake? Language?

Comment: I'm using their [API](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/reference.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is not valid JSON, but the return can arrive in a slightly different format:

```
{
    "resultSetMetaData": {
        ...
        "data": 
        [
            {
                "Name": "Kelly",
                "Email": "kelly@email.com"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Fisher",
                "Email": "fisher@email.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

To get the API to send it that way, you can change the SQL from `select *` to:

```
select object_construct(*) as KVP from "USER";
```

You can also specify the names of the keys using:

```
select object_construct('NAME', "NAME", 'EMAIL', EMAIL) from "USER";
```

The object_construct function takes an arbitrary number of parameters, as long as they're even, so:
`object_construct('KEY1', VALUE1, 'KEY2', VALUE2, <'KEY_N'>, <VALUE_N>)`

Comment: Thank you for the help!

My next step is to find a way to remove the escape characters: 
["{\n \"Name\": \"Kelly\",\n\"Email\": \"kelly@email.com\" \n}, ],  
To:  
[{ "Name": "Kelly", "Email": "kelly@email.com" },],  


I just found sql-mode to NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPE, yet it would enable again as default once the sql was restarted.
Do you know if there is a way to do it in the query as well?

Comment: UPDATE: I used a replaceAll() action and removed these characters.